# Troubleshooting JS formula for summing a single cell across multiple Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to sum a single cell across multiple Google Sheets. I've been using this script for a few weeks and it recently stopped working. Sheets either doesn't recognize the name of the formula, or when it does, it times out in the loading process:

```
function sumCells(cell) {
var val = [];
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function (s) {
          val.push(Number(s.getRange(cell).getValue()))
    });
return val.reduce(function (accumulator, value) {
    return accumulator + value;
    });
}
```

I know it's not a problem with the individual cells because I've tried pulling the numbers from each of the sheets and summing them in the same sheet and there were no errors.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to fix the code, or another solution besides this script? The number of sheets we use is constantly changing, so using `SUM(Sheet1!B5+Sheet2!B5...SheetN!B5)` isn't an option.

Comment: Were you able to check your logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check your Execution log of your script so we can see what is the exact error?

[image: logs]

#### Edit:

- It seems that your issues stems on the limit on execution time. Execution per script should not be more than 6 minutes, or else it will cut it short and fail.
- Apps script should have no problem handling big data but the one that is slowing down your script is the API calls.
- I have found a formula from this [add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/formulas_by_top_contributors/515924842729) that might solve your issue if that is an option:

  - `UTIL_UTIL_VALUESHEETS(A1notation)`
  - [Usage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf9vgxxA57o)

#### Reference:

- [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)
- [Add on reference](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/55910585/find-the-sum-of-all-c2-cells-across-all-sheets-in-a-google-spreadsheet?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! I tried summing the cells directly instead of using an array but it still gave me an error. I also tested the script on fewer sheets and it worked, so I think the issue is the amount of data being combed through. The execution log is saying the "argument cannot be null", but I think that's because I'm running the function in the Scripts environment, not on the actual spreadsheet where I would call the function on a specific cell, right? Apologies, this is my first time using JS with a Google Sheet!

Comment: how many sheets do you have when it fails? can you log every sheet name inside for each function when you have a lot of sheet names? you might need to debug to identify what caused the issue. I'm not really sure until i can see the exact data. @csecrepublic

Comment: I was looking at the wrong log--the actual execution log says "Exceeded maximum execution time" for every run. Right now we have 66 sheets, and I know it was working when we had ~10 sheets. I'm 90% sure it's an issue with the amount of data.

Comment: yes, we have a limit on execution time, which is 6min per execution. If your script goes past that, that will be the error message.

Comment: hi @csecrepublic, I have found an add-on that might help you, see my updated answer above.

Comment: If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) @csecrepublic

Comment: Thanks, I tried the add-on and unfortunately it's not working for me. I'm going to try to try working with a smaller range of sheets and get a representative data set. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem @csecrepublic, if we answered or help you with your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved or not.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)